# QGIS, labels offset for a line layer

Tags: qgis, labeling, offset

I am working with rule based labels on a line layer and need to move the labels along different axes along the line. I want to move the label `2` along the line a few millimeters.

For the label `2`, the placement is a curve, and the position is above the line. The labels `1` and `2` will repeat after 15 millimeters, and I need the label `2` to be offset from the label `1` along the line by a few millimeters. There is a distance parameter, but it is responsible for the offset not along the line, but across.

[image]

Сurrent setting for the first label[image]

Current setting for the second label[image]

Comment: Please refrain from reposting your question instead of improving the existing one. Even deleting the old question doesn't exempt you from this rule.

Comment: Oh, and as with the old question: Please add your exact label settings, thank you.

Comment: @Erik, my current settings
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydQ2W.jpg

Comment: Please [edit](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/372430/edit) your question so it contains all necessary informations. Searching the comments for information is a hassle.

Comment: Where does the other label come from?

Comment: What other label? Perhaps the problem is that I attached an image not of my settings, but they are exactly the same. My qgis is not in English and I think that many parameters will be difficult to read.

Comment: There are two labels, 1 and 2, and you only explained how 2 is created.

Comment: The first label has a placement-curve, position - on the line. But I don't need to shift it, I need to figure out how to shift the "2" label along the line.

Comment: Yeah, and where does the bloody label come from? Is it a different layer, a different feature, a duplicate layer?! This is relevant when it comes to shifting the 2nd label, because if they were on the same layer, the solution would be quite different from the different-layer-solution.

Comment: I'm sorry. I changed the description